# Sort a list of objects based on the String pattern of object attribute

Tags: spring-boot, criteriaquery

I have a list of Device objects.
With attributes:
userId,
activationDatetime,
and others.

User ID is constructed as:
aaaaXXXX -> aaaa-> string, xxxx->number
aaaa String part can start with HCAD, GSAD, SLAD, GLAD, HCZD

Normally the string sort would yield
GSAD0000, GLAD0000, HCAD0000, HCZD0000, SLAD0000

I want to customize the sort. Such that the list of objects are ordered by prefix in the following order.
HCAD0000
HCAD0001
GSAD0000
GSAD0001
SLAD0000
SLAD0001
GLAD0000
HCZD0001........and so on

How to achieve this in Spring. What is the most efficient way to do this?

SELECT user_id, device_id
FROM (
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'HCAD%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'GSAD%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'SLAD%'
UNION all
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'GLAD%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'HCZD%'
)
ORDER BY
CASE
WHEN user_id LIKE 'HCAD%' THEN 1
WHEN user_id LIKE 'GSAD%' THEN 2
WHEN user_id LIKE 'SLAD%' THEN 3
WHEN user_id LIKE 'GLAD%' THEN 4
WHEN user_id LIKE 'HCZD%' THEN 5
END,
user_id;

the query works fine. but i cannot seem to able to implement it in code

Answer (score 0):

To achieve custom sorting in Spring, you can use Spring Data JPA and make use of the JPA `@Query`

First define entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "db")
public class Device {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "device_id")
    private String deviceId;

    // ... other attributes, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

then create a repository with your query (using order to achieve your custom sorting, i took in consideration that your query is working

```java
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
           value = "SELECT user_id, device_id FROM (" +
           " SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'HCAD%' UNION ALL" +
           " SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'GSAD%' UNION ALL" +
           " SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'SLAD%' UNION ALL" +
           " SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'GLAD%' UNION ALL" +
           " SELECT * FROM db WHERE user_id LIKE 'HCZD%'" +
           ") ORDER BY " +
           "CASE " +
           "WHEN user_id LIKE 'HCAD%' THEN 1 " +
           "WHEN user_id LIKE 'GSAD%' THEN 2 " +
           "WHEN user_id LIKE 'SLAD%' THEN 3 " +
           "WHEN user_id LIKE 'GLAD%' THEN 4 " +
           "WHEN user_id LIKE 'HCZD%' THEN 5 " +
           "END, user_id")
    List<Device> findAllOrderedByUserId();
}
```

Finally, implement the service:

```java
@Service
public class DeviceService {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceRepository deviceRepository;

    public List<Device> getDevicesInOrder() {
        return deviceRepository.findAllOrderedByUserId();
    }
}
```